# How does the cloud animation in Weather app work?

Tags: ios, animation, view, background, weather

I'm building an app in which I'd like to have animations of weather like in the weather app, I mean when it shows the clouds moving and rain falling etc in the background, and also animations like the application CALM when you seen high quality videos on the background.

My question is - are those just high quality videos / animations that just sits on the background of the view ? or is it another technology core animation / openGL etc.. ? if so which class handles those type of things?

sorry if the question is too stupid , never handled those kind of animations ....

Thanks.

Comment: Jack, have you figured this out yet?

Comment: Hey not really, but I guess u can use a video controller in the background , or take some uiimage and animate their movement ..., I ended up going in another direction with the app...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/38860350/763355

Answer (score 0):

For the rain/snow animation, you could use CAEmitterLayer to achieve.

You definitely could use gif or video to play in background but it would cost your CPU, CAEmitterLayer is processed with GPU, which would be a much relief.

Check this tutorial

https://www.invasivecode.com/weblog/caemitterlayer-and-the-ios-particle-system-lets/?doing_wp_cron=1474449715.0338420867919921875000

For cloudy/fog/sun animation, I suppose it would be achieved with UIImageView animation.

Check the tutorial

http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-animation-uiimageview/

For the second animation, there may be better solutions, hope someone to post.